# Virtual Reality and Sort of kinetic concept

Tags: face-recognition, virtual-reality

Firstly sorry in advance I might sounds stupid to you guys. I am working on a project feasibility what i need is make a game using e.g. WEB GL when I start game it capture my photo and generate my 3D character throughout the game..

I am wondering if such thing is possible or not, searching for it but never yet found

or

Is there a possibility to develop such game for Android & iOS platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely  it is possible.

May be adobe Recap-360 will help you in this case. Integration with the software may solve your problem but software is in nascent stage.

IF you connect skynect software may be  help as well.

kindly explain your exact requirement.

Regards

Comment: Let me explain you must have played GTA V instead of GTA V character e.g. Trevor i want my character automatic generated using webcam face have to be mine throughout the whole game (GTA V is used just as example here it will be my own 3D Game)